# Inverse a filter in ng-repeat - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I understand this sort of questions have already been answered. But there is something I am stuck at.

My JSON data looks like:

```
[{
  "batch_queue_name": "Batch One",
  "start_date": "12/01/2016 10:18 P.M.",
  "end_date": "12/03/2016 01:08 A.M.",
  "completion_status": "100"
}, {
  "batch_queue_name": "Batch Two",
  "start_date": "12/10/2016 12:18 A.M.",
  "end_date": "12/11/2016 05:23 P.M.",
  "completion_status": "100"
}, {
  "batch_queue_name": "Batch Three",
  "start_date": "04/01/2017 12:18 A.M.",
  "end_date": "06/01/2017 03:21 P.M.",
  "completion_status": "60"
}, {
  "batch_queue_name": "Batch Four",
  "start_date": "05/01/2017 01:25 A.M.",
  "end_date": "06/01/2017 12:30 A.M.",
  "completion_status": "97"
}, {
  "batch_queue_name": "Batch Five",
  "start_date": "05/01/2017 12:18 A.M.",
  "end_date": "08/01/2017 03:37 A.M.",
  "completion_status": "42"
}, {
  "batch_queue_name": "Batch Six",
  "start_date": "16/10/2016 12:18 A.M.",
  "end_date": "18/10/2016 05:23 P.M.",
  "completion_status": "100"

}]
```

Now, in my `ng-repeat` I am trying to filter those which do not have a completion status of 100:

```
<tr ng-repeat="batch in vm.batches | filter: {batch.completion_status:'!'+'100'}">
     <td> ... </td>
 </tr>
```

But this throws an error:

> Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 28 of
>   the expression [vm.batches |NaNilter: {batch.completion_status !=
>   '100%'}] starting at [.completion_status != '100%'}].

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write `batch.completion_status`. You can do it like this:

```
ng-repeat="batch in batches | filter: {completion_status: '!100'}"
```

### [Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j67rejes/)

Comment: Why we don't need to call `batch.completion_status` but simply `completion_status`?

Comment: @Sai As we are looping over `batches` in `ng-repeat`, Angular knows we are "talking" about `batch`

Answer (score 1):

`batch.completion_status` is not required. 
Just put :

---

`<tr ng-repeat="batch in vm.batches | filter : {completion_status:'!'+'100'}">
  </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this kind of controller logic:

```
 $scope.filterRange = function(obj) {
    return obj.completion_status != 100;
 };
```